# how to append on sibling in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code

```
<div class="data">
    
    <div class="another"></div>
    <!-- need to add element here -->
    
</div>
```

I want to add the element where I put comment using jQuery how I can append sibling of another using jQuery

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you specifically want to insert after the `another` `div` element, try [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$('<div>Another 2</div>').insertAfter($('.another'));
```

In the `$('.another')` part, you can otherwise specify the target more precisely.

Comment: I prefer this to `.after()` as it returns the element you are adding (rather than the one you are adding *to*) - obviously depends what you need.

Answer (score 50):

I think you want to use the [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) function:

```
$('div.another').after('<div>');
```

Comment: jQuery 1.12.1 this works (but previously mentioned `.insertAfter` does not)

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
$('div#data').append('your HTML');
```

Comment: While this will work in his specific example. It won't work if he has more than one inner div and wants to specifically insert the new element after one of them.

Comment: It won't even work with this specific example. The selector is selecting by **id**, while the outer div has a **class**